# How can i Post Forms in new window with angular js

Tags: angularjs, http

I am using a external Payment solution, which require redirects user to custom page based on request params to API.

What am trying to do, is to extend my form data in the controller before posting to the Web Service and Post the the Data trough a new window or modal.

basically the same thing i would achieve without angular.js, by simple putting this in the form element:

```
<form ame="formname" action="http://www.mycustomdomain.com" method="post" target="_blank">
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Replace the `action` attribute with the [ng-submit directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). Use the [$http.post Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) to POST data. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: sorry, i dont thinks you got my question right? i am actually using the ng-submit directive already, only as mentioned after validating i need to post this Data to a url, which then redirects me to the payment interface of third party providers